# Changing datasource dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, combobox

I have a WinForms combobox that is bound to a list of objects list this:

```
BindingList<myObject> myListOfObjects = new BindingList<myObject>();

// 100 objects are added to myListOfObjects

bindingSource1.DataSource = myListOfObjects;
comboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Each instance of my object contains the following:

```
public string Name
public int Index
public List<int> Codes = new List<int>();
```

The object also implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

When an objects "Name" is selected in the combobox, I want to databind a listbox to the "Codes" list for the selected object.  I'm trying to do this as such:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.DataSource = myListOfObjects[((myObject)comboBox1.SelectedValue).Index].Codes;
}
```

This doesn't work and I get an InvalidCastException (specifically that Int32 can't be cast as myObject).  Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `combobox1.SelectedValue` will be set to the `myObject` property that is specified in the `ValueMember` of the combobox.

In order to get the underlying `myObject`, you need to use `comboBox1.SelectedItem`:

```
listBox1.DataSource = myListOfObjects[((myObject)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Index].Codes;
```

If this were my code, I would also double-check to ensure that SelectedItem is not null before using it directly:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null) {
    listBox1.DataSource = myListOfObjects[((myObject)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Index].Codes;
} else {
    listBox1.DataSource = null;
}
```